# I am trying to get a value from my array but it is always blank

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to display data from an array in my React component.

I can see the data I need in the browser developer console from the `console.log()`:

```
FinalRecords.js :: recordTitle: (4)

0: {members: Array(10), id: 62, title: 'RR 1980 Record 1', storeId: 1088}
1: {members: Array(10), id: 63, title: 'RR 1980 Record 2', storeId: 1088}
2: {members: Array(10), id: 64, title: 'RR 1980 Record 3', storeId: 1088}
3: {members: Array(10), id: 65, title: 'RR 1980 Record 4', storeId: 1088}
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to get the `title`.

I've tried a bunch of different things, with this one be the most recent:

```
    render() {
        const { recordId, records, bandName } = this.props;

        var data = records.filter((r) => r.id === recordId);

        var records = data.toArray();

        console.log("FinalRecords.js :: recordTitle: ", records);

        return <div> record - {findRecordTitle(records, recordId) }  - {bandName || ''} </div>
    }

}

function findRecordTitle(records, id) {
    return records.find((record) => {
        return record.id === id;
    })
}
```

I need to get the `title` of the record by using the `id`.

But it just is always blank.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `r.id = recordId` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: Where specifically are you trying to display the "title"?  You have a function called `findRecordTitle`, which returns either an object from the array or `null`.  Did you mean to use a `title` property on that resulting object somewhere?

Comment: @David Yeah I am trying to display the `title`

Comment: @trincot omg...ok I changed it to `===`

Comment: How do you have `records` defined both using `const` and `var`

Comment: @KevinB with an error, no doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of this function implies that you expect it to return a "title" (which I would interpret as a string value):

```
function findRecordTitle(records, id) {
    return records.find((record) => {
        return record.id === id;
    })
}
```

However, nothing in this function in any way references a "title".  It returns a matching object from the `records` array (or `null`).  If you want to return only a `title` property from that object, just return that property:

```
function findRecordTitle(records, id) {
    return records.find((record) => {
        return record.id === id;
    })?.title; // <--- here
}
```

---

Edit: In case your JavaScript environment can't use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), you can explicitly check for `null` before trying to use the object:

```
function findRecordTitle(records, id) {
    const record = records.find((record) => {
        return record.id === id;
    });
    return record ? record.title : null;
}
```

Or perhaps default to an empty string instead of `null`, etc.

Comment: I am getting an `Unexpected token` javascript erorr on the `?.title;` part

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell: Sounds like your JavaScript environment is a bit out of date then.  (The syntax is called "optional chaining".)  In that case you can manually check for `null` before referencing the `title` property.  I've updated the answer with an example.